# List Comprehension in a function

Tags: python

So I'm trying to write a function for a hangman game that will return a string that is composed of lowercase English letters - all lowercase English letters that are not in lettersGuessed. I can't see to get the list comprehension to work

```
def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
    '''
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string, comprised of letters that represents what letters have not
      yet been guessed.
    '''

    [letterGuessed.remove(letter) if letter in'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' for letter in lettersGuessed ]
```

Comment: Why do you need list comprehension to begin with? Also there's no return in your function. Also, you don't need to remove things, just add it to your comprehension list you're creating? `[x for x in lettersGuessed if x not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of expanding on @scoJo's response, here's my take.

```
import string    

test_guesses = ['a','b','f']

def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
    # Note that we're ensuring that input letters are lowercase when being compared to the list.
    return ''.join([i for i in string.ascii_lowercase if i.lower() not in lettersGuessed])
```

With the original response, you were removing letters from the letters guessed list, not the alphabet.

My solution also taps into the string standard library of Python to create a list of letters without having to ensure that you've typed each one.

If you want to return a list, just remove the .join() function.

Input:

```
getAvailableLetters(test_guesses)
```

Output:

```
'cdeghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[letter for letter in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' if letter not in lettersGuessed]
```

To give more of an explanation as to why this works, it helps to consider and list comprehension as the following:

`[ expression for item in list if conditional ]`

In our case, `list` is the letters of the alphabet. 
Our `expression` is simply the individual letter in the `list` and our `conditional` is if the letter does not already exist in `lettersGuessed`.

The nice thing is that it almost translates into an english sentence which should make it easy to understand.

> Give me each letter in the alphabet if the letter is not in the list of guessed letters

I would recommend having a read through this article as having a good understanding of list comprehensions will be a huge benefit for your python coding.
https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Comment: Best to add a bit of explanation what is wrong with the original code and how your's solves it

Comment: that would be appreciated if you could explain what'swrong with mine

Comment: @Jk128711 To break your solution down in the same way, it would read "For each guessed letter, if it is in the alphabet, remove it from the guessed letter list". Which is obviously not what you intended.

Comment: Ahhh I understand than you

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity i'd propose using [Python sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

A set is an "unordered collection of unique elements"

```
def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
    # convert to set
    all_letters_set = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
    letters_guessed_set = set(lettersGuessed)
    # substract sets
    available_letters = list(all_letters_set - letters_guessed_set)
    # convert list of str to single str
    return ''.join(available_letters)
```

This way you can do a simple subtraction to retrieve the list of available letters and then join this list to a single string.

No manual iteration needed

*Note: if you want to preserve the sorted order of the letters still available, use Pythons sort function before returning the string*

```
available_letters.sort()
```